# Inline edit focus is not un-focusing after saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid in my application. We have functionality to do inline editing and saving.Now editing is working fine but the problem is with focus. When i click on edit button all cells are focused as expected and later i perform modifications and save, now focus from that row won't go off.

Code what I have tried is:

col name and col model code:

```
colNames: ['Id','Category Name','Category Label','Sort Order','Default','Active','Action'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'id', hidden : true, key : true},
        {name:'CategoryName',index:'1',sortable:false, width: 343, editable: true, 
         editoptions:{size:"40",maxlength:"40"}
        },
        {name:'CatLable', index:'2',width:250, editable: true,edittype:"select",
         editoptions:{value:"#{contexts.sessionContext.get('categoryLabel')}"}
        },
        {name:'DispOrder',index:'3',sortable:false, width: 100, align:"center", editable: true, editrules:{number:true},
         editoptions:{size:"3",maxlength:"3"}
        },
        {name:'IsDefault',index:'4',sortable:false,width:60,search:false, resizable: false},
        {name:'IsActive',index:'5',sortable:false,width:60,search:false, resizable: false},
        {name: 'Action', index: '6', width: 85, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
        }
        }
    ],
```

format options code:

```
{name: 'Action', index: '6', width: 85, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: {
        // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
        url: "#myurl",
        keys: true,
        "delbutton":false,
        onEdit:function(rowid) {
            lastsel2 = rowid;
        }
    }
}
```

Reload grid code:

```
gridComplete: function(){
    unblockB2BUI();
    var recs = parseInt(jQuery("#categoryResults").getGridParam("records"),10);
    if (recs == 0) {
        jQuery("#logGridWrapper").hide();
        jQuery(".noResMsg").show();
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".noResMsg").hide();
        jQuery('#logGridWrapper').show();
    }
}
```

Grid for editing:
[image]

Grid when try to save the edited values:
[image]

**Update:**
Grid after saving and going to edit one more row:
[image]

Someone please suggest me  how can I come out of the focus when i click on save icon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: function saveEdit(id) {
    /* your code */
        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSelectRoot);
        lastSelectRoot = null;
}

Comment: First of all: **which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use**? Seconds the problem itself is unclear for me. You wrote "When i click on edit button all cells are focused as expected", but I would say that all editable columns will be converted in editing controls and **the first field** only will get the focus. You wrote "i perform modifications and save, now focus from that row won't go off". It seems that **saving to the server was not successful**. Which `editurl` you use? Do you make local editing or saves the data directly to the server. Please describe the problem more clear.

Comment: @Oleg Guriddo jqGrid JS 4.7.0 is the fork and version. As in third snap shot(updated), on click of save icon for any row, focus is not been hidden.

Comment: one says that some control (like input field) has focus if characters typing on the keyboard will be forwarded to the control. So it's wrong to say "all cells are focused" because only one control (one input field) could have the focus. In the same way it's wrong to say "any row, focus is not been hidden". Focus can't be hidden. What you probably mean is that the editing row stay editing. It means typically that posting the modified data to `url: "#myurl"` was unsuccessful. By the way Guriddo jqGrid JS exist strarting with 4.7.1. 4.7.0 is just jqGrid. Can you provide the demo to the problem?

Comment: I recommend you to try to change URLs to jqGrid to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can use direct URLs to CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). In the way you can verify whether you have some serious problem in your code or it could be a bug in the version of jqGrid, which you use.